# Nullable object must have a value ASP.NET MVC datetime picker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

It is really confused why my view does not bind data into model when save data into controller. I created this UI using Jquery Datetime Picker. After Submit button message raised **"Nullable object must have a value"** tried to debug and this error is indicated to my date start and date end view because those data never binding (no value/null) into model.

[image]

based on that UI I wanna save those data into sql server database using EF. My Model is Datetime type.

My Model:

```
public class OvertimeRequestModel
{
    public int OvertimeId { get; set; }
    public string OvertimeCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; } //datetime format
    public DateTime? DateEnd { get; set; } //datetime format
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I used texboxfor in the view:

```
 <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateStart, @"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "date-timepicker1", @placeholder = "select date start", required = "required", @autocomplete = "off" })
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
    </span>
</div>

 <div class="input-group col-xs-10 col-sm-5">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateEnd, @"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "date-timepicker2", @placeholder = "select date End", required = "required", @autocomplete = "off" })
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o bigger-110"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(function ($) {

        if (!ace.vars['old_ie']) $('#date-timepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss',//use this option to display seconds
            icons: {
                time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
                date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                today: 'fa fa-arrows ',
                clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                close: 'fa fa-times'
            }
        }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
            $(this).prev().focus();
        });

        if (!ace.vars['old_ie']) $('#date-timepicker2').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
            icons: {
                time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
                date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                today: 'fa fa-arrows ',
                clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                close: 'fa fa-times'
            }
        }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
            $(this).prev().focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Controller:

```
OvertimeRequest over = new OvertimeRequest();
over.OvertimeCode = model.OvertimeCode;
over.DateStart = model.DateStart; //always get null value
over.DateEnd = model.DateEnd; //always get null value
over.Notes = model.Notes;
db.OvertimeRequest.Add(over);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Need suggest, thanks.

Comment: What happens if you don't use the `datetimepicker`? Just to ensure that it is not interfering with the binding, try removing it and check whether the binding works.

Comment: If it's a required field, why is it nullable?

Comment: @RonBeyer this is just reflection from Entity Framework.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal when i tried to remove `datetimepicker` i still get Null value

Comment: Can you try to put this annotation on your datetime fields, `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]` The fields might be null, because it is expecting the data in different format.

Comment: `over.DateStart` - is this nullable as the `model.DateStart`? If not then you have to assign the value not the object like `model.DateStart.value`. Or have the date objects nullable in the Entity Models too. You can also have some null checking like `if(model.DateStart.Hasvalue)` and then assign accordingly.

Comment: @Rahatur yes, both `over.DateStart` and `model.DateStart` are nullable. according me this is because html helper does not understand that datetime format into model

Comment: @PriyankPanchal I tried to add `DisplayFormat` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have a little tricky to solve this problem. Just change my data type from datetime to be string. The problem is because html helper cannot recognized datetime format to store into controller.

```
public string DateStart { get; set; } 
public string DateEnd { get; set; }
```

view just the same posted above:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateEnd, @"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "date-timepicker2", @placeholder = "select date End", required = "required", @autocomplete = "off" })
```

and controller to save this data is:

```
OvertimeRequest over = new OvertimeRequest();
over.OvertimeCode = model.OvertimeCode;
over.DateStart = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DateStart, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null); //i think this is the most important thing
over.DateEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DateEnd, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null); //i think this is the most important thing
over.Notes = model.Notes;
db.OvertimeRequest.Add(over);
int result = db.SaveChanges();
```

Finally All worked well.

Answer (score 1):

View

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "date-picker fullwidth", data_date_format = "dd.mm.yyyy" })
```

Js

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({ autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true });
```

model

```
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: How does it store `Null` in the database in case user wants to leave this field empty? User should not see any default date in there in case the field is empty right?